Mass changing printer's settings. Web-request?
There is a task to change settings on 200 printers: DNS server IP address. All printers have the same model, login and password. I'm thinking about changing settings of one printer on web interface and recording web requests, then sending those web requests to other printers. Is it even possible? How do I do that? Which software is best to use for this task?

it may be possible (if the application is written just right for your desires) but by the time you have troubleshot it to the point its reasonably reproducible, you'll have spent more time and effort than just changing them. I'd start by reaching out to the vendor support, and see what they offer.

I have written countless print drivers.  Like @FrankThomas said.. reach out to the vendor.  Internally and possibly externally, they will probably have tools or methods for this.  I had to manipulate settings on over 200 local and remote driver instances for testing.  They probably need to do the same.
